# Good introductory book on mathematical morphology

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

What is a good introductory book on mathematical morphology? It should outline the basic theory and a focus on applications would be nice. If possible, it should be approachable for a determined undergrad.

Thank you.

**EDIT**: The field is relatively new I guess, so if there indeed doesn't exist any introductions yet, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good book is "Mathematical Morphology" edited by Laurent Najman and Hugues Talbot, Wiley, 2010. It's translated from a French version (2008, 2010). The introductory chapter is a good overview, and the other chapters are more specialized accounts.